# How can I know when the route completes processing a directory in camel?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

How can I get a trigger once my route completes processing a directory and its sub directories in camel ? Is there any way I can specify this in the route ?

Comment: show us your route where you define to process directory and sub directory? You can use `.onCompletion()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if its `from("file:..")` then its a batch consumer, and you can find the information on the last file which has a message header with `CamelBatchComplete` with the value `true`.

See more details at the Camel website: http://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html

Comment: can it be done if its not from("file:..") ? Will it be possible to do for the first child level ?